# Setting Public Extensions for Journey Builder Activities in App Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, appcenter

After creating an Application Extension App in App Center, you can create a Journey Builder Activity and define the endpoint to the application extension. In this modal dialog, there is a Public Extension setting that enables you to determine whether the extension is available for:

- Only this application, or
- This application and other installed applications

Can someone confirm what this actually does? What does "This application and other installed applications" actually mean and how does a Public Extension work?

The [developer documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/creating-platform-activities.html) explains:

> Public Extension: Please select "This application and other installed applications", more information coming soon about this

I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me what this does and what the differences are between these two options.

[image: Creating a Journey Builder Activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just affects visibility.  The engineers didn't want to assume that all extensions were available everywhere in an account.  I believe it's just allowing this component to either be accessed and ran within the context of the same application or by other applications (appId's), like Journey Builder.